# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model in nextjs13

Tags: mongodb, next.js13

error - MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "post".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
at Mongoose.model (/Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:549:13)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/lib/mongodb/models/post.ts:34:52)
at (api)/./src/lib/mongodb/models/post.ts (/Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/.next/server/pages/api/post.js:62:1)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/.next/server/webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/post.ts:9:82)
at (api)/./src/pages/api/post.ts (/Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/.next/server/pages/api/post.js:82:1)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/.next/server/webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
at **webpack_exec** (/Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/.next/server/pages/api/post.js:92:39)
at /Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/.next/server/pages/api/post.js:93:28
at Object. (/Users/mac/Practice/portfolio_projects/ai-image-generation/.next/server/pages/api/post.js:96:3)

**for db connection**

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};
let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

**Post.tsx **

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import Joi from "joi";

type post = {
  name: string;
  prompt: string;
  photo: string;
};

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  prompt: { type: String, required: true },
  photo: { type: String, required: true },
});

function validatePost(data: post) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    prompt: Joi.string().min(2).required(),
    photo: Joi.string().min(0).required(),
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
}

const Post = mongoose.model("post") || mongoose.model("post", PostSchema);

export { validatePost };
export default Post;
```

**
Where i called post modal**

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb/mongodb";
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import Post from "@/lib/mongodb/models/post";
import { validatePost } from "@/lib/mongodb/models/post";

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: "50mb",
    },
    responseLimit: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  await clientPromise;
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    try {
      const posts = await Post.find({});
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: posts });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Fetching posts failed, please try again",
      });
    }
  } else if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { error } = validatePost(req.body);
      if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
      const { name, prompt, photo } = req.body;
      const photoUrl = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(photo);
      const post = new Post({
        name,
        prompt,
        photo: photoUrl.url,
      });
      const newPost = await post.save();
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: newPost });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Unable to create a post, please try again",
      });
    }
  }
}
```